# Library with identifier rc is missing

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm currently using a library for my script. The script is working fine when I use the spreadsheet as an owner but when I use the spreadsheet as a user, there is an error that says

[image: error]

Here's my library

[image: Library]

And here's the script that I use in the said spreadsheet

```
//save as pdf
function exportNamedRangesAsPDF(){
 rc.exportNamedRangesAsPDF();
}
```

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user must have at least read access to the library.

*Edited*

As [@mateo-randwolf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65046330/library-with-identifier-rc-is-missing/65046483?noredirect=1#comment115037900_65046483) said below It would be good to share the reference https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#sharing_a_library

> To share your library with others:
>
> - Grant at    least read-level access to all potential users of the library.

Comment: I need to deploy it as a web app, right? My `execute the app as: User accessing the web app` then the `who has access to the app: Anyone`. The error is still there.

Comment: Nope. It may not be necessary.

Comment: To complete this answer I would like to include the reference to the part regarding sharing a library to other users, check it [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#sharing_a_library). What are you exactly trying to do? What do you mean by ```I need to deploy it as a web app```?

Comment: On the publish menu, there's a lot of `deploy as` an option, right? That's what I'm talking about, but it's fine now so thank you!